# Want to Read vs Wish List in iBooks?

Tags: books

In macOS iBooks I can add a book to "Wish List" while in iOS iBooks I can add a book to "Want to Read". Are these lists not related? Is there no way to see the on iOS books I expressed an interest in while I happened to be on macOS, or vice versa?